# How do I write generic Java method and compare two variables of the generic type inside the method?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have written the following code:

```
private static <T> T getMax(T[] array) {
        if(array.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        T max = array[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > max)
                max = array[i];
        }
        return max;
    }
```

The problem is in this line: `if(array[i] > max)`.

I understand that Java can't understand the `>` operator in case of unknown/arbitrary classes.

At the same time, I don't want to write different methods for the objects of the classes that I know I'll be sending.

***Is there a workaround?***

Comment: Your best bet is to force that the type T must be Comparable. You can change it to `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` then use `compareTo`.

Comment: Or use a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change `T` to `T extends Comparable<T>` and use the `compareTo` method. That is:

- `private static <T extends Comparable<T>> T getMax(T[] array)`, and
- `if (array[i].compareTo(max) > 0) { ... }`

But note that you can use

```
maxElement = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a workaround, by adding a `Comparable` upper bound to `T`.

Because the `<` operator doesn't work on objects, you must use the equivalent functionality, which is the `compareTo` method in the `Comparable` interface.

Ensure that the type `T` is `Comparable` by providing an upper bound.

```
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> T getMax(T[] array)
```

Then, in place of the `>` operator, call `compareTo`:

```
if(array[i].compareTo(max) > 0)
```